React Native CLI: Gradle Build Failure - Error Resolving Plugin com.facebook.react.settings
I recently installed the React Native Community CLI and tried creating a new project. However, when running the project, I encountered the following error during the Gradle build process:
    info Installing the app...  

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details  

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor  

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  

* Where:  
Settings file 'I:\Projects\MapApp\android\settings.gradle' line: 2  

* What went wrong:  
Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings']  

> java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (I:\Projects\MapApp\android\.gradle\8.10.2\dependencies-accessors\...) to immutable location (I:\Projects\MapApp\android\.gradle\8.10.2\dependencies-accessors\...)  

* Try:  
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.  
> Run with --scan to get full insights.  

BUILD FAILED in 40s  

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.  

I have already been working on another React Native project, and it builds and runs without any issues.
This error appears only with the newly created project.
I have ensured that my development environment is set up correctly by running npx react-native doctor.
i have :
Verified that Java and Android SDK are installed correctly.
Cleared the .gradle cache using gradlew clean.
Restarted the system and reinstalled dependencies.
but still not working.

I'm having same problem, but I figure out that inside the android folder delete .gradle
this will fix the issue
